# Compute$ \int_{\|z -3\| = 6} \frac{z }{(z-2)^3(z + 4)} \, dz $

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate

$$ \int_{\|z -3\| = 6} \frac{z}{(z-2)^3(z + 4)} \, dz $$

I don't know how to compute this. I do not know if I should do the integral and after that, substitute $z$ for $(z-3)$. And I don't know how I should use the 6. I know that I am inside a disc of radius $6$ and centered in $3$, but I don't know how to use this information at the time of doing the integral. I know I am supposed to use Cauchy, but believe me, I am lost. Also, the book I am using uses other notation an this confuses me.

Comment: Here's a hint: Use $f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-3| = 6} \frac{f(s)ds}{(s-z)^{n+1}}$, where you can modify the integrand to get your $f$.

Answer (score 0):

partial fraction decomposition gives you $$\frac{z}{(z-2)^3(z+4)} = \frac{-1/54}{z-2} + \frac{4/27}{(z-2)^2}+\frac{1/3}{(z-2)^3}+\frac{1/54}{z+4}$$
the only pole in the interior is at $z = 2,$  therefore 
$$\int_{||z -3|| = 6} \frac{z }{(z-2)^3(z + 4)}dz = -2\pi i\left(\frac1{54}\right).$$